# mongodb first self join and then join with another table based on some conditions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql

I have two collections, transaction and attributes. I want first to get the instrumntIds based on input conditions from **transaction** collection and then self join to find all the same instrumntIds from this collection. please improve my code, here I tied group but then my query is not getting the data so I removed group part from the query.

```
db.transaction.aggregate([
          {
            $lookup: {
              from: "transaction",
              localField: "data.instrumentId",
              foreignField: "data.instrumentId",
              as: "s2"
            }
          },
          {
            $match: {
              "data.postingDate": {
                $gte: ISODate("2022-01-01"),
                $lte: ISODate("2022-01-31")
              }
            }
          },
          {
            $project: {
                _id:0,
              "data.instrumentId": 1,
              "data.postingDate": 1
            }
          }
        ])
```

now I want to join this output data with second collection(**attribute**) based on instrumentId and postingDate. and want to get status from the attribute collection and amount from transaction collection.

I am new on mongo so I have confusion like how to self join first and then join with second collection here is my code

```
db.getCollection("transaction").aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "attributes",
      let: {
        postingDate: "$data.postingDate",
        instrumentId: "$data.instrumentId"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                { $eq: ["$postingDate", "$$postingDate"] },
                { $eq: ["$instrumentId", "$$instrumentId"] }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "attributes"
    }
  },
  {
                $unwind: "$attributes"
            },
  {
    $match: {
      "data.postingDate": {
        $gte: ISODate("2022-01-01"),
        $lte: ISODate("2022-01-31")
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { 
      instrumentId: "$attributes.instrumentId",
        status: "$attributes.status"
      },
      instrumentIds: { $first: "$data.instrumentId" }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      amount: "$data.amount",
      status: "$attributes.status",
      instrumentIds: "$instrumentIds"

    }
  }
])
```

Here is my transaction collection

```
[
{
    "postingDate": "1/1/2023",
    "instrumentId": "Type_1",
    "Amount": " $2,000,000.00 "
},
{
    "postingDate": "1/4/2023",
    "instrumentId": "Type_2",
    "Amount": " $700,000.00 "
},
{
    "postingDate": "1/4/2023",
    "instrumentId": "Type_3",
    "Amount": " $400,000.00 "
},
{
    "postingDate": "2/1/2023",
    "instrumentId": "Type_1",
    "Amount": " $10,000.00 "
},
{
    "postingDate": "2/4/2023",
    "instrumentId": "Type_2",
    "Amount": " $4,000.00 "
},
{
    "postingDate": "2/4/2023",
    "instrumentId": "Type_3",
    "Amount": " $2,000.00 "
},
{
    "postingDate": "3/2/2023",
    "instrumentId": "Type_2",
    "Amount": " $3,900.00 "
},
{
    "postingDate": "3/4/2023",
    "instrumentId": "Type_3",
    "Amount": " $1,950.00 "
},
{,
    "postingDate": "4/1/2023",
    "instrumentId": "Type_2",
    "Amount": " $3,900.00 "
},
{
    "Accounting Period": "Apr-23",
    "postingDate": "4/6/2023",
    "instrumentId": "Type_3",
    "Amount": " $1,950.00 "
},
{
    "postingDate": "5/1/2023",
    "instrumentId": "Type_2",
    "Amount": " $3,900.00 "
},
{
    "postingDate": "5/6/2023",
    "instrumentId": "Type_3",
    "Amount": " $1,950.00 "
},
{
    "postingDate": "5/15/2023",
    "instrumentId": "Type_1",
    "Amount": " $500,000.00 "
},
{
    "postingDate": "6/15/2023",
    "instrumentId": "Type_2",
    "Amount": " $3,500.00 "
},
{
    "postingDate": "6/15/2023",
    "instrumentId": "Type_3",
    "Amount": " $1,700.00 "
},
{
    "postingDate": "6/15/2023",
    "instrumentId": "Type_1",
    "Amount": " $100,000.00 "
}
```

]

and attribute collection is

```
[
{
    "postingDate": "1/1/2023",
    "instrumentId": "Type_1",
    "status": "A"
},
{
    "postingDate": "1/4/2023",
    "instrumentId": "Type_2",
    "status": "A"
},
{
    "postingDate": "1/4/2023",
    "instrumentId": "Type_3",
    "status": "A"
},
{
    "postingDate": "2/1/2023",
    "instrumentId": "Type_1",
    "status": "A"
},
{
    "postingDate": "2/4/2023",
    "instrumentId": "Type_2",
    "status": "A"
},
{
    "postingDate": "2/4/2023",
    "instrumentId": "Type_3",
    "status": "A",
},
{
    "postingDate": "3/2/2023",
    "instrumentId": "Type_2",
    "status": "A"
},
{
    "postingDate": "3/4/2023",
    "instrumentId": "Type_3",
    "status": "N"
},
{,
    "postingDate": "4/1/2023",
    "instrumentId": "Type_2",
    "status": "A"
},
{
    "Accounting Period": "Apr-23",
    "postingDate": "4/6/2023",
    "instrumentId": "Type_3",
    "status": "N"
},
{
    "postingDate": "5/1/2023",
    "instrumentId": "Type_2",
    "status": "A"
},
{
    "postingDate": "5/6/2023",
    "instrumentId": "Type_3",
    "status": "N"
},
{
    "postingDate": "5/15/2023",
    "instrumentId": "Type_1",
    "status": "N"
},
{
    "postingDate": "6/15/2023",
    "instrumentId": "Type_2",
    "status": "A"
},
{
    "postingDate": "6/15/2023",
    "instrumentId": "Type_3",
    "status": "A"
},
{
    "postingDate": "6/15/2023",
    "instrumentId": "Type_1",
    "status": "A"
}
```

]

my expected result for the 'postingDate = 4/30/2023' will be look like

```
    [
  {
    "_id": {
      "postingDate": "4/1/2023",
      "status": "A"
    },
    "allAmountsInstrumentId": [
      {
        "amount": " $700,000.00 ",
        "instrumentId": "Type_2",
        "postingDate": "1/4/2023"
      },
      {
        "amount": " $4,000.00 ",
        "instrumentId": "Type_2",
        "postingDate": "2/4/2023"
      },
      {
        "amount": " $3,900.00 ",
        "instrumentId": "Type_2",
        "postingDate": "3/2/2023"
      },
      {
        "amount": " $3,900.00 ",
        "instrumentId": "Type_2",
        "postingDate": "4/1/2023"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "postingDate": "4/6/2023",
      "status": "N"
    },
    "allAmountsInstrumentId": [
      {
        "amount": " $400,000.00 ",
        "instrumentId": "Type_3",
        "postingDate": "1/4/2023"
      },
      {
        "amount": " $2,000.00 ",
        "instrumentId": "Type_3",
        "postingDate": "2/4/2023"
      },
      {
        "amount": " $1,950.00 ",
        "instrumentId": "Type_3",
        "postingDate": "3/4/2023"
      },
      {
        "amount": " $1,950.00 ",
        "instrumentId": "Type_3",
        "postingDate": "4/6/2023"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

my expected result for the 'postingDate = 05/31/2023' will be look like

```
    [
  {
    "_id": {
      "postingDate": "5/15/2023",
      "status": "N"
    },
    "allAmountsInstrumentId": [
      {
        "amount": " $2,000,000.00 ",
        "instrumentId": "Type_1",
        "postingDate": "1/1/2023"
      },
      {
        "amount": " $10,000.00 ",
        "instrumentId": "Type_1",
        "postingDate": "2/1/2023"
      },
      {
        "amount": " $500,000.00 ",
        "instrumentId": "Type_1",
        "postingDate": "5/15/2023"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "postingDate": "5/1/2023",
      "status": "A"
    },
    "allAmountsInstrumentId": [
      {
        "amount": " $700,000.00 ",
        "instrumentId": "Type_2",
        "postingDate": "1/4/2023"
      },
      {
        "amount": " $4,000.00 ",
        "instrumentId": "Type_2",
        "postingDate": "2/4/2023"
      },
      {
        "amount": " $3,900.00 ",
        "instrumentId": "Type_2",
        "postingDate": "3/2/2023"
      },
      {
        "amount": " $3,900.00 ",
        "instrumentId": "Type_2",
        "postingDate": "4/1/2023"
      },
      {
        "amount": " $3,900.00 ",
        "instrumentId": "Type_2",
        "postingDate": "5/1/2023"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "postingDate": "5/6/2023",
      "status": "N"
    },
    "allAmountsInstrumentId": [
      {
        "amount": " $400,000.00 ",
        "instrumentId": "Type_3",
        "postingDate": "1/4/2023"
      },
      {
        "amount": " $2,000.00 ",
        "instrumentId": "Type_3",
        "postingDate": "2/4/2023"
      },
      {
        "amount": " $1,950.00 ",
        "instrumentId": "Type_3",
        "postingDate": "3/4/2023"
      },
      {
        "amount": " $1,950.00 ",
        "instrumentId": "Type_3",
        "postingDate": "4/6/2023"
      },
      {
        "amount": " $1,950.00 ",
        "instrumentId": "Type_3",
        "postingDate": "5/6/2023"
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Please add what is the expected output.

Comment: @CharchitKapoor I updated the collections and mentioned the expected output.

Comment: The question is not very clear. 1. Why do you need to self join if you don't have the `instrumentId` on your expected results. 2. The data on the expected results is not consistent with the sample data.

Comment: consider change your structure of a transaction to something like: `{"postingDate": ISODate("2023-01-01"), "instrumentId": "Type_1", "Amount": 2000000, "currency": "USD"}`

Comment: @nimrodserok here i need instrumentId, because based on this instrumentId i will find same instrumentId wehn the postingDate condition match, we can ignore currency for now

Comment: Does [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KM_wliNbyWi) answer your question?

Comment: thanks @nimrodserok for the help, but here it is giving me the result without self joining. i need first to self join the transaction collection to get all the instrumentIds and then join with attributes, but here it give the result without self join. so the query looks good, only here I need first self join. please if you can add that code too. thanks

Comment: It is not clear why do you need to self join. How does this affect the final result?

Comment: without self join how I will find all the instrumntIds, suppose for the input postingDate '5/1/2023', the instrumentId for this record is 'Type_2' so first I need to find all the 'Type_2' instrumentIds. there are total 6 Type_2 instrumentIds , without self join ,is there any way to find all these 6 Type_2 instrumentIds?

Comment: @nimrodserok so first I need to sum the amount for 6 "Type_2  instrumentId" nd join with attribute collection to get the attributes for each matching record

Comment: Even if they have different `postingDate`? Each document should have the sum of the amount of its own ` instrumentId`?

Comment: @nimrodserok no, it will be the sum of all matching instrumentIds, suppose 'Type_2' is six time so the sum of all 6 records first in transaction collection

Comment: Does [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8cBnSjGrxlA) answers it? You can use `$setWindowFields` to sum the amounts per ` instrumentId`

Comment: @nimrodserok there is still a small issue like if we consider the postingDate '6/15/2023' here Type_1,Type_2 and Type_3 exist against this post. and then again these 3 instrumentIds(Type_1,Type_2 and Type_3), the self join should get all the collections, because all the collections has oly these three instrumentIds, so for the postingDate the sum should be the sum all records ie (2461,250.00 )

Comment: Does [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DRUVb13G9uP) answer your question?

Comment: @nimrodserok now it give me the sum, but the sum is wrong, as I have updated the question and I added the expected result there above. so it does not match the expected result.
my expected result for the 'postingDate = 5/1/2023' will be look like

Posting   Status    Balance
5/1/2023  A         $684,300.00 
my expected result for the 'postingDate = 6/15/2023' will be look like

Posting   Status    Balance
6/15/2023  A            $2461,250.00

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255234/discussion-between-nimrod-serok-and-user1872177).

Comment: Does [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/28MRmUVJSid) answers your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want something like this:

```
db.transactions.aggregate([
  {$match: {$expr: {
        $lte: [
          {$dateFromString: {
              dateString: "$postingDate",
              format: "%m/%d/%Y"
          }},
          ISODate("2023-04-30")
        ]
  }}},
  {$setWindowFields: {
      partitionBy: "$instrumentId",
      output: {allAmounts: {
          $push: {amount: "$Amount", postingDate: "$postingDate"},
          window: {documents: ["unbounded", "unbounded"]}
      }}
  }},
  {$match: {$expr: {$gte: [
          {$dateFromString: {
              dateString: "$postingDate",
              format: "%m/%d/%Y"
          }},
          ISODate("2023-04-01")
  ]}}},
  {$lookup: {
      from: "attributes",
      let: {
        postingDate: "$postingDate",
        instrumentId: "$instrumentId"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {$match: {$expr: {$and: [
                {$eq: ["$postingDate", "$$postingDate"]},
                {$eq: ["$instrumentId", "$$instrumentId"]}
        ]}}},
        {$project: {status: 1, _id: 0}}
      ],
      as: "attributes"
  }},
  {$unwind: "$attributes"},
  {$group: {
      _id: {
        postingDate: "$postingDate",
        status: "$attributes.status"
      },
      allAmountsInstrumentId: {$first: "$allAmounts"}
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jWxr7aZ7kGb)

For mongoDB versions older than 5.0, you can replace the `$setWindowFields` with a `$lookup` stage:

```
 {$lookup: {
      from: "transactions",
      localField: "instrumentId",
      foreignField: "instrumentId",
      pipeline: [
        {$match: {$expr: {$lte: [
                {$dateFromString: {
                    dateString: "$postingDate",
                    format: "%m/%d/%Y"
                }},
                ISODate("2023-04-30")
        ]}}},
        {$project: {
            amount: "$Amount",
            postingDate: 1,
            _id: 0
        }}
      ],
      as: "allAmounts"
  }},
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bKd0FW9Fz-Y)

Comment: I am using mongo version 4.4.11 and $setWindowFields is not working on it. is there any alternative for it

Comment: `$lookup` is an alternative

Comment: {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        instrumentId: "$data.instrumentId",
        postingDate: "$data.postingDate"
      },
      allAmounts: {
        $push: {
          amount: "$data.amount",
          postingDate: "$data.postingDate",
          instrumentId: "$data.instrumentId"
        }
      }
    }
  },
I changed setWindowFields to this logic but the self join part is not working

Comment: I am trying to remove $setWindowFields block, because my mongo version is old and it is not supporting the $setWindowFileds, please any help for this

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly